# Set jsp page as a div content in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, extjs

In my J2EE web application I've used Extjs. I am brand new to J2EE. There is a button(plan) in a layer.

Here is my javascript file code segment for creating a button in the layer.

```
contentE1 : 'tourPlanning',     //my layer
    title : 'Tour Planning',
    items : [ new Ext.Button({
        text : 'Plan',
        handler : function() {

            document.getElementById("mapView").innerHTML = '\TourPlan.jsp';

        }
    }),
```

What I want is I need to set a jsp page(TourPlan.jsp) as a  content(for my mapView div-I have a Google map view in my page). The output becomes, it sets the map view div content to **Tourplan.jsp**.

My TourPlan.jsp file(as an example) if like this.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Tour Plan</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Plan Your Tor</h1>

<!-- More Content Here -->

</body>
</html>
```

I am new to all of these thing, so I would be much appreciated if anyone could be so kind enough to explain how should I do such a thing.

Comment: why are you trying from JavaScript to include a file, why not from jsp?

Comment: actually this is someones' project.i am doing some modifications. my mainPanel is a javascript file.there is button in this main panel.when user clicks this button new layout should be loaded inside the existing div

Comment: I have posted the answer, Please check.

Comment: If the below answer helped you, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
<div id="mapView" style="display:hidden;">
  <%@ include file="TourPlan.jsp" %>
</div>

<script>
contentE1 : 'tourPlanning',     //my layer
title : 'Tour Planning',
items : [ new Ext.Button({
    text : 'Plan',
    handler : function() {

        document.getElementById("mapView").style.display="block";

    }
}),
</script>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This mapView div is declared in another file.then how can I use this?

Comment: If you have include your javascript file there than you will be able to use it.